# SUM two CASE functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to SUM two CASE functions that I just created in my query. I need both of these columns to return in my result set, but also need the sum of the two columns to return in another column as 'DegreeDays.' I tried the SUM function, but to no avail, and I tried a simple a 'HeatingDegreeDays + CoolingDegreeDays AS DegreeDays' and that didn't work either. Suggestions?

```
  ,CASE
    WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
    WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
   END AS HeatingDegreeDays

  ,CASE
    WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
    WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
   END AS CoolingDegreeDays
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to simply make your existing query into a [derived table](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-derived-tables-to-calculate-aggregate-values):

```
SELECT a.HeatingDegreeDays,
    a.CoolingDegreeDays,
    a.HeatingDegreeDays + a.CoolingDegreeDays as DegreeDays
FROM
(
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
        WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
        WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
        WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
       END AS HeatingDegreeDays

      ,CASE
        WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
        WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
        WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
        WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
       END AS CoolingDegreeDays
    FROM MyTable
) AS a; -- Derived tabled aliased as "a"
```

If you're on SQL Server 2005 or greater, this would also work just as well as a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
        WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
        WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
        WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
       END AS HeatingDegreeDays

      ,CASE
        WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
        WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
        WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
        WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
       END AS CoolingDegreeDays
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT HeatingDegreeDays,
    CoolingDegreeDays,
    HeatingDegreeDays + CoolingDegreeDays as DegreeDays
FROM cte;
```

Either of these would seem to be better to maintain than repeating the logic and hard-coded values of your query just to make a calculation.

Answer (score 4):

You can repeat the formulas:

```
  ,CASE
    WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
    WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
   END +
   CASE
    WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
    WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
   END AS TotalDays
```

Or you can put it in a subquery (or CTE) and say:

```
select . . .,
       (HeadingDegreeDays + CoolingDegreeDays) as TotalDays
```

Comment: Thank you. Truly appreciate it. I tried that earlier, but I must have had the syntax screwed up.

Comment: I must say that I don't find the suggestion of duplicating code to be a good practice, especially when there are simple and elegant alternatives (that you do mention in the second half of the answer). Is there a performance benefit in doing that?

Comment: @TimLehner . . . The performance should be pretty similar in SQL Server for the two solutions.  Some databases (notably MySQL) might materialize the subquery, and that could have a big negative effect on performance.

Comment: Ah, how unfortunate! Thanks for another lesson, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

When you derive column names in the `SELECT` part of your query you cannot reference them in other parts.

You have two basic options:

Define DegreeDays as the `SUM` of your two `CASE` statements (repeating all the logic) or doing something like:

```
select ...,HeatingDegreeDays,CoolingDegreeDays,DegreeDays=HeatingDegreeDays+CoolingDegreeDays
from table
cross apply (select
CASE
    WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
    WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
   END AS HeatingDegreeDays

  ,CASE
    WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
    WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
   END AS CoolingDegreeDays
) x
```

Answer (score -1):

```
,CASE
    WHEN TempLow > 60.5                     THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) > 60.5    THEN ((60.5-TempLow)/4)
    WHEN  TempHigh >= 60.5                  THEN (((60.5 - TempLow)/2)-((TempHigh-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempHigh < 60.5                    THEN (60.5-(TempHigh+TempLow)/4)
   END AS HeatingDegreeDays

  ,CASE
    WHEN TempHigh < 66.25                   THEN 0
    WHEN ((TempHigh + TempLow)/2) < 66.25   THEN ((TempHigh-66.25)/4)
    WHEN  TempLow <= 66.25                  THEN (((TempHigh - 66.25)/2)-((66.25-TempLow)/4))
    WHEN TempLow > 66.25                    THEN ((TempHigh+TempLow)/2)-66.25
   END AS CoolingDegreeDays
```